# Why is is my program not pulling in the files from the folder

Tags: java

I have a program that is suppose to read all the files in my folder and combine the files into on file and place them into a new folder. Some of the files are not being pulled in and I do not know why.

The file names are wonder1.txt, wonder2.txt, wonder3.txt, and wonder4.txt and the folder name is Alice, but only a few of the files are actually in the new folder.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;



public class alice {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
      File folder = new File("/Users/DAndre/Desktop/Alice");

        //Reads in all the files in that folder 

        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            String fileName =  fileEntry.getAbsolutePath();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            try {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = br.readLine();

                while (line != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                    stringBuilder.append("\n");
                    line = br.readLine();
                }


                /**
                * Pass original file content as string to another method which
                * creates new file with same content.
                */

                newFile(stringBuilder.toString());

             } finally {
                br.close();
             }
        }

  }

  public static void newFile(String fileContent) {
    try {
        String newFileLocation = "/Users/DAndre/Desktop/final/final_copy.txt";
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(newFileLocation);
        writer.write(fileContent);//Writes original file content into new file
        writer.close();
        System.out.println("File Created");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me guess, only one file is in `final_copy.txt`? Maybe it is because `new PrintWriter(newFileLocation);` will truncate the content of the given file, if it already exsists, as you can read in the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Also, you are saying "`File folder = ....`". I think you need something that has Folder object, not File object. Because you are doing `new File(/Users/DAndre/Desktop/Alice)`, but it seems to me that the path given is a folder, not file.

Comment: @hagubear That my friend, might not be true. It says `An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.` on Doc:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: Yes it is a folder, and inside are the files that I need to read in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that you haven't initialize PrintWriter in append mode, because of which the new file gets overwritten with the content of the last file that was written.

```
 public static void newFile(String fileContent) {
try {
    String newFileLocation = "C:\\Users\\Shayan\\Desktop\\files2\\final_copy.txt";
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(newFileLocation),  true /* append = true */));
    writer.write(fileContent);//Writes original file content into new file
    writer.close();
    System.out.println("File Created");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

The last argument in the constructor of FileOututStream is set to true, indicating that it should be opened in append mode.

Comment: sorry I changed the folder paths for my computer, but I hope you get the idea :)

Comment: It works, but how can I get them to be in order like the files are part of a story, so its wonder1.txt, wonder2.text, and so on

Comment: If you know the order of the files at compile time then one thing that you can do is to first read and save all files in an ArrayList, then call the method newFile on these files in whatever order you desire

Comment: Alright, also I notice that the new file is reading in each file more than once. I only want them to be read in one time only.

Comment: I guess you must have run the program more then once, the writer opens the file in append mode because of which the content that the file already contains is not deleted, so it appears that it is reading files more then once when actually the additional content is from the previous run.

Comment: Glad to have been a help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(newFileLocation);
```

to

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFileLocation, true)))
```

Little explanation: append meant to write it additively, on the contrary write overrides the existing file. In your code you are creating a new file including one of your wonders, but on next iteration the file is recreated. So the content of previous wonder is gone.

With the change PrintWriter object is not recreating the file, instead it writes content to a BufferedWriter which also transfers the stream to an append able FileWriter object.

Little suggest: do not create a PrintWriter object on each iteration.

Second little suggest: You don't need PrintWriter. BufferedWriter itself is good enough as far as I see.

Comment: I think you should add a little explanation to why `write` is wrong and `append` is correct.

Comment: `append` is not correct. It doesn't change much if you re-creacte the writer.

Comment: @Tom you are right, I generally don't need PrintWriter on my projects. Fixed it now.

Comment: The change to `writer.append(fileContent)` is not necessary. It also works with `writer.write(fileContent)`.

Comment: @Tom you are pushing me not to use PrintWriter at all :) .

Comment: Not really, I'm just saying what I think :D. `PrintWriter` is maybe not the best solution here, but we are on Stackoverflow and not CodeReview :D.